# how to add a button beside left bar controller or right bar controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i add buttons just beside a left `barButton` or just beside  `rightbarButton`,
i mean i need to have more than 2 buttons on the title bar is that possible?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

As drawn from [this blog post](http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html):

> Think of a toolbar as your container,
>   instead of the UIView object. And
>   since a UIToolBar is UIView based, it
>   can be added to the right side of a
>   nav bar using the above trick. The
>   following code shows how you can add
>   two standard buttons to the right
>   side:

```
// create a toolbar to have two buttons in the right
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44.01)];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// create a standard "add" button
UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a spacer
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a standard "refresh" button
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// stick the buttons in the toolbar
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

[buttons release];

// and put the toolbar in the nav bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
```

Also check the SO post

[Adding buttons to navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900252/adding-buttons-to-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view with two buttons in your leftBarButton -

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftBtnsView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `UISegmentedControl` to hold all your buttons and use
`[[UIButton alloc] initWithCustomView:]` to show the segment control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how you could go about doing this. I am using a `MasterDetailView` template that comes with the top navigation bar for this example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    leftButton.title = @"Left button";
    rightButton.title = @"right button";
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}
```

Comment: This was not the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, there's something called UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItems

> UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
>   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(something)];
>
> UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
>   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.png"]
>   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
>   action:@selector(something)];
>
> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[settingsButton, menuButton];

Answer (score 0):

i think you need something like this

```
 UIBarButtonItem *firstButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
 UIBarButtonItem *secondButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=@[firstButton, secondButton];
```

it will add two bar button items on left of navigation bar. you can make it on right side the same way

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=@[firstButton, secondButton];
```